# How to convert stream data to object?

Tags: c#, dll, methods, stream

I have a dll which stores image resources , font resources etc...

I have a class in the assembly which has a return method that I want to be able to pull resources from the dll and return them as an abject which I can then convert to its respective type .

here is the code I have so far.

```
        public class GetResource
    {
            public static T LoadDllResource<T>(string ResourceFolder, string resourceName, string Extension, int width = 10, int height = 10)
            {
                Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(myAssembly.GetName().Name + "." + ResourceFolder + "." + resourceName + "." + Extension);

// convert stream to object by doing something like this (I'm not sure)
//return (T)Convert.ChangeType(EndResultOFStreamConversion, typeof(object));
            }
    }
```

and use it this way

```
    Font SomeFont1=  GetResource.LoadDllResource<Font>("Resources","Splash","ttf")

UnityEngine.Texture2D SomeImage2=  GetResource.LoadDllResource<UnityEngine.Texture2D>("Resources","SnowImage","png")
```

Let me know if there is a problem with the question. Thanks for any help !

I am working in the Unity Engine which does not nicely support mixed assemblies using System.Drawing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Image.FromStream Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx) within the `System.Drawing` namespace to convert a stream to an image *(be sure to add a reference to System.Drawing.dll to your assembly first)*. I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'font resources' but I'd do it this way:

```
public class GetResource
{
    public Image GetImageFromResource(string resourceFolder, string resourceName, string extension)
    {
        return Image.FromStream(this.GetStreamFromResource(resourceFolder, resourceName, extension), true);
    }

    private Stream GetStreamFromResource(string ResourceFolder, string resourceName, string Extension)
    {
        Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(myAssembly.GetName().Name + "." + ResourceFolder + "." + resourceName + "." + Extension);

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh , I wont need to Use System.Drawing to do this huh . I didnt know that . Unfortunately I am working i nthe UnityEngine and the UnityEngien does not support System.Drawing well in mixed assemblies . I will edit the question to include that.

Thanks.

Oh , Also . i just need to have the method handle more than just the Image type . but String,Font, Texture2D,  whatever other class  .

Comment: I have no experience with Unity. But, you shouldn't use the generic method in your question. That would require you to check for the type of T (if T = image .. if T = font ..) that is a real bad practice and should never be used.

Comment: How can I then return an object of type (T) that i am attempting to pull from the dll ?
if i want a Font file from the dll i would  say 

` Font SomeFont1=  GetResource.LoadDllResource<Font>("Resources","Splash","ttf")`

if i wanted a Texture2D image i would say

 `UnityEngine.Texture2D SomeImage2=  GetResource.LoadDllResource<UnityEngine.Texture2D>("Resources","SnowImage","png")`

and just to point out , in the auto generated resource designer , i replace System.Drawing.Bitmap with UnityEngine.Texture2D